Shopware 6.6: How to hydrate the StorableFlow store with data?
I've added a FlowAction that works fine, except for storing data within the StorableFlow. I'd really like to understand how to hydrate it properly.
Here is my current FlowAction:
class SameDayMailAction extends FlowAction 
{
 ...
    public function requirements(): array
    {
        return [OrderAware::class];
    }
...
    public function handleFlow(StorableFlow $flow): void
    {
        if (!$flow->hasStore(OrderAware::ORDER)) {
            $this->logger->error(json_encode($flow->getStore(OrderAware::ORDER)));

            return;
        }

        $order = $flow->getStore(OrderAware::ORDER);
        $orderId = $flow->getStore(OrderAware::ORDER_ID);

        $this->logger->debug('orderid' . $orderId);

        $currentDate = (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d');
        $orderDate = $order->getOrderDate()->format('Y-m-d');

        if ($currentDate !== $orderDate) {
            return;
        }

        $this->samedayRepository->create([[
            'id' => Uuid::randomHex(),
            'orderId' => $orderId,
            'clicked' => false
        ]], $flow->getContext());
    }

}

The flow is being triggered correctly, but in the logs, I see app.ERROR: null [] [].
Any advice on how to properly hydrate the StorableFlow would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

OrderAware only transmit the orderId not the entire order entity. If you need the data of the order you must load the entity via the repository.
  public function __construct(
        private readonly EntityRepository $orderRepository
        ...
    )
    {
    }
...
    public function handleFlow(StorableFlow $flow): void
    {
        if (!$flow->hasData(OrderAware::ORDER_ID)) {
            return;
        }
        $criteria = new Criteria([$flow->getData(OrderAware::ORDER_ID)]);
        $order = $this->orderRepository->search($criteria, $flow->getContext())->first();
        if (!$order) return;
        ... 
     }



After some research I found out that this is not completly true.
Since 6.5 or 6.6 the entities can be lazy loaded by the OrderStorer according to this documentation: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/adr/2022-07-21-adding-the-storable-flow-to-implement-delay-action-in-flow-builder.html
More important is, that the orderId is not unique anymore, the primarykey is a orderId, versionId combination.

Good to know that you can now lazy load the data in flows, another lesson learnt
